# How to get only the number/s from an Id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, substring

I've following line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');//The value it contais e.g. blacklistgrid_1

});
```

Now I want only `1` in this case in another variable. The no. could be diferent as the no. of HTML elements generated could be more so in future there could be ids like blacklistgrid_12, blacklistgrid_7, blacklistgrid_103, etc. In each of these case the logc should return me 12, 7, 103, etc. from the respective ids. How to achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: `table_id.match(/\d+/)[0]`

Comment: @ArunPJohny:Thanks for your help. It really did the magic for me.

Comment: You should instead, use `data-` attribute for this kind of things..

Answer (score 2):

```
var num=table_id.split("_")[1]
```

this will give the number.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
  var parts = table_id.split('_');
  var num = parts[1]; // it would be the number you want
```

For more detail on `split()` check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Or you may try the following:

```
var regex = /.*_(\d+)/;
var num = table_id.replace(regex, '$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

[CLick for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2e4yQ/)

```
var str ="blacklistgrid_1";
var s1 = str.substr(str.indexOf("_")+1,str.length);

alert(s1);
```

Code in context of your program

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');//The value it contais e.g. blacklistgrid_1

var number = table_id.substri(table_id.indexOf("_")+1),table_id.length);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

try js' `parseInt()` to get the number out.

Comment: `parseInt` would get the number if the id is like `1_blacklistgrid`